# Why is an error thrown from within an async function inside a bluebird promise not caught in the .catch() function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

In the following code example the function baz() throws a TypeError, when invoked within the `fs.open` callback inside the `new Promise` callback the node process exits immediately with a non-zero value and the exception is never caught.

```js
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var fs = require('fs');

function baz() {
  [].toDateString(); // should throw type error
}

function bar() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.open('myfile', 'r', (err, fd) => {
      baz();  // throws TypeError [].toDateString which is never caught.
      return resolve('done');
    });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('caught errror');
    console.log(error);
    return Promise.resolve(error);
  });
}

bar()
  .then((ret) => {
    console.log('done');
  });
```

Output:

```
 $ node promise_test.js
 /Users/.../promise_test.js:5
 [].toDateString(); // should throw type error
    ^

 TypeError: [].toDateString is not a function
   at baz (/Users/..../promise_test.js:5:6)
   at fs.open (/Users/..../promise_test.js:12:7)
   at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
✘-1 ~/
```

If I modify this code slightly to throw the exception in the promise callback but outside of the `fs.open` callback the exception is caught as expected and execution continues:

```js
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
 baz();  // throws TypeError [].toDateString
 fs.open('myfile', 'r', (err, fd) => {
   console.log(err);
   return resolve('done');
 });
```

Output:

```
$ node promise_test.js
  caught errror
  TypeError: [].toDateString is not a function
  ...
  done
```

Comment: Because it's in an async function, not a bluebird function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the exception occurs inside the `fs.open()` async callback so that exception goes back into the async event handler in `fs.open()` that called the completion callback where it then disappears and has no chance to be propagated anywhere.  Bluebird never has a chance to see it.

This is a textbook example of why you should not mix regular async callback code with promise code.  Instead, promisify `fs.open()` and use the promisified version and then the exception will be caught appropriately by the promise infrastructure.

```
fs.openAsync = function(fname, mode) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        fs.open(fname, mode, function(err, fd) {
            if (err) return reject(err);
            resolve(fd);
        });
    });
}

function bar() {
  return fs.openAsync('myfile', 'r').then(function(fd) {
      baz();  // throws TypeError [].toDateString which will now be caught
              // in the .catch() below
  }).catch(function(err) {
    // handle error here
  });
}
```

Or, in Bluebird, you can use the built-in promisify functions:

```
const fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs'));
```

That will automatically create `fs.openAsync()` which returns a promise and promisified versions of all the other async methods.

---

FYI, the promise infrastructure can only catch exceptions in callbacks that are called by the promise infrastructure itself.  It does that by wrapping the call to each callback in it's own try/catch.  As you see in your code, you are using the `fs.open()` callback directly which has no such chance to get wrapped in such a try/catch handler to catch the exception and turn it into a rejection.  So, instead, the usual solution is to create a promisified version of `fs.open()` that immediately rejects or resolves in the callback and then your custom callback code goes in the `.then()` handler where the callback is wrapped and exceptions will be caught and automatically turned into rejections.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this clears up my misunderstanding.  A short follow on question.  Any exception thrown from within the async function(even if it's wrapped in a promise)  will not be caught in the .catch() function?  eg. If I invoke baz() within the promisified fs.open it will also not be caught?

Comment: @JaredS - In the code I show, an exception in `baz()` will be caught and turned into a rejection which will show in the `.catch()` in my answer.  An exception inside a `.then()` handler will be caught by that `.then()` and will turn the current promise chain into a rejected promise which will skip any subsequent `.then()` handlers and will call the next `.catch()` handler.

Comment: I had to use: `var fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs'));` with Bluebird 3.5.1.

Comment: @CoreyS. - Yes, that was a typo in my answer which I have corrected.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks! I almost edited, but I wasn't sure if that was syntax from an older version or not.

Answer (score 0):

This article seems to provide some guidance on promises swallowing exceptions, and how BlueBird can help in handling them:

```
Promise.onPossiblyUnhandledRejection(function(error){
    throw error;
});
```

> And on the odd chance you do want to discard a rejection, just handle
>   it with an empty catch, like so:
>
> Promise.reject('error value').catch(function() {});

http://jamesknelson.com/are-es6-promises-swallowing-your-errors/

Comment: Thanks for your response but this isn't an unhandled rejection, it's an exception being thrown and not caught.  I think a more relevant document is this: http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/catch.html which states: '.catch is a convenience method for handling errors in promise chains. It comes in two variants - A catch-all variant similar to the synchronous catch(e) { block.'  My question asks why the exception isn't caught.

Comment: @JaredS because it's not in a promise chain